# Should there be a policy on hammering zero value answers to closed questions?

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about people trying to build low rep simian/bot armies by answering close-able questions others wouldn't touch and thought:

Why shouldn't *Community* downvote zero value answers to punish that behavior?

I just thought I'ld open the topic for discussion.

Comment: how would community decide what to downvote?

Comment: Closed question contains zero vote answers.

Comment: That doesn't mean the answers are bad. For example, I could provide a stellar answer to a duplicate without realizing it was a dupe. The question is then closed and nobody bothers to upvote my answer. That doesn't suggest that my answer was bad.

Comment: @terdon - fair enough.  if that happened to me, i would ask for a merge though.